# How can I multiply multiple dataframes of a list by each observation of a vector?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list of dataframes that I would like to multiply for each element of vector.

The first dataframe in the list would be multiplied by the first observation of the vector, and so on, producing another list of dataframes already multiplied.

I tried to do this with a loop, but was unsuccessful. I also tried to imagine something using map or lapply, but I couldn't.

```
for(i in vec){
  for(j in listdf){
     listdf2 <- i*listdf[[j]]
    }
}

Error in listdf[[j]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Any idea how to solve this?

*Vector and the List of Dataframes have the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Map` :

```
listdf2 <- Map(`*`, listdf, vec)
```

in `purrr` this can be done using `map2` :

```
listdf2 <- purrr::map2(listdf, vec, `*`)
```

---

If you are interested in `for` loop solution you just need one loop :

```
listdf2 <- vector('list', length(listdf))
for (i in seq_along(vec)) {
   listdf2[[i]] <- listdf[[i]] * vec[i]
}
```

**data**

```
vec <- c(4, 3, 5)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 3:7)
listdf <- list(df, df, df)
```

Comment: I tried `Map` but was unsuccessful because:
`Error in FUN (left, right): non-numeric argument to binary operator`
Perhaps because the dataframes have some NA or NULL data?

`purrr::map2` and loop solution produce a list with "NULL dataframes"

Comment: @jpoa It works for me for the data I have used in my post using which you can test that the answer works. Make sure you have data in a similar reproducible fashion so that we can test the solutions. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).